# How to send HTML form data basically file <input type="file" name="file" value=""> to desktop using html

Tags: html, css, forms, file, download

We are working on a project where we are using form tag to access a file from our system and then download it back to our system basically on the desktop using html .

I am expecting the file to be saved on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to do it. You have to get the file in the input, create create a link for this object and set the link into the `<a>` href. You can try this code :

```html
<input type="input" id="inputFile" />
<a id="downloadLink">Download the file</a>

<script>

const fileInput = document.getElementById("inputFile")
const downloadLink = document.getElementById("downloadLink")

fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (!fileInput.files.length) return;
    const urlObj = URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0])
    downloadLink.href = urlObj
})

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).